Load MIDI file : unable to load asset
I got a problem loading SoundFound from midi pro. Each time I try to load it, with
await midiPro.loadSoundfont(sf2Path: r'assets\sf2\GrandPiano.sf2', instrumentIndex: 0);

I receive:
Exception has occurred. FlutterError (Unable to load asset: "assets\sf2\GrandPiano.sf2". The asset does not exist or has empty data.)
My sf2 is from musescore (YDP-GrandPiano-SF2-20160804) and said to be widely used.
in pubspec:
assets : 
  - assets/sf2/GrandPiano.sf2

which matches: file structure
I tried downloading other soundfount, checking the path and the directory, updating pubspec.yaml, using flutter clean but none of that work. What more should I do ?
If you need more information, please let me know.
